# Changing a TabbedPane index from an outer class

Tags: java, swing, jtabbedpane

I have a TabbedPane in a class called *App* and i want to run a method in this class. I added two tabs with a JPanel from the class *Login* and an empty one. Here is the class:

```
public class App {
private static JTabbedPane tabbedPane;
public JPanel mainPanel;

public App(){
    tabbedPane.addTab("Login", new Login().mainPanel);
    tabbedPane.addTab("test", new JPanel());
    changeFocus(0);
}

public void changeFocus(int i){
    //CODE HERE
}
```

}

Now i want to run a method called `changeFocus()` from an outer class. A added an actionListener to the *Login* class with a constructor like this:

```
public Login() {
        logInButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
               App.changeFocus(1);
            }
        });
    }
```

Now i ask why this doesn´t work and `changeFocus()` must be **static**. And if i change it to **static** why the *JTabbedPane* cannot be static and throws out an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply pass `App` as an argument to `Login`'s constructor:

```
 tabbedPane.addTab("Login", new Login(this).mainPanel);
```

and then:

```
public Login(App app) {
    logInButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
           app.changeFocus(1);
        }
    });
}
```